# User to import XLSM files into Oracle APEX

Tags: excel, oracle-apex, xlsm

Is there a way where the user can import **XLSM** (macro) files?

I'm building an application and the user would have to import their files which are `Excel` with macros. For this application I would only need certain data from these files, like columns with payment amounts and due dates.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options for loading Excel formatted files into the database.

Jeff Kemp has a great summary of options. 
https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2018/11/load-spreadsheet-data-into-apex/

Historically I like using Anton's plugin, since it took a spreadsheet of any format, and gave me an Oracle table full of all the worksheet rows & columns.

There are more native options now.

You won't get any macro content, but you shouldn't need it.